# Scale to fit contents to Canvas when factor is smaller than 1

Tags: wpf, canvas, scale

With code below every seems to be working fine when the scaleX and scaleY are larger than 1 (e.g. this.Width becomes 100 -> 100/83.25 = 1.20. But when these values go below 1 (e.g. this.Width becomes 50 -> scaleX = 50/83.25 = 0.600) the presented sphere is larger than excpected.

Is there any formula to calculate the correct scaling value when the size becomes lower than the actual bound of the canvas contents?

Given the following XAML file:

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:xxx" x:Class="xxx.MainTile"
        Title="Easy uploader" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" ResizeMode="NoResize" ShowInTaskbar="False" Icon="quercis.ico" Topmost="True" WindowStyle="None" Loaded="Window_Loaded" SizeChanged="Window_SizeChanged">
    <Grid>
        <local:Tile HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" x:Name="Tile" >
        </local:Tile>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And the corresponding Tile class:

```
public partial class Tile : Canvas
{
    public static int MinTileSize = 50;
    private TileSize tileSize = TileSize.Large;

    public delegate void TileSizeChangedDelegate();
    public event TileSizeChangedDelegate TileSizeChanged;
    public TileSize TileSize
    {
        get { return tileSize; }
        set
        {
            TileSize orgTileSize = tileSize;
            tileSize = value;
            //TileCanvas.Width = TileCanvas.Height = 80;
            switch (tileSize)
            {
                case EasyUploader.TileSize.Small: this.Width = MinTileSize; this.Height = MinTileSize; break;
                case EasyUploader.TileSize.Medium: this.Width = 2 * MinTileSize; this.Height = 2 * MinTileSize; break;
                case EasyUploader.TileSize.Wide: this.Width = 4 * MinTileSize; this.Height = 2 * MinTileSize; break;
                case EasyUploader.TileSize.Large: this.Width = 4 * MinTileSize; this.Height = 4 * MinTileSize; break;
            }

            if (this.Parent.GetType() == typeof(MainTile))
            {
                Registry.SetCurrentUserValue("MainTileSize", value.ToString());
            }

            if ((orgTileSize != tileSize) && (TileSizeChanged != null))
                TileSizeChanged();

            double scaleX = this.Width / canvasBounds.Width; //if (scaleX < 1) scaleX = -1 * (canvasBounds.Width / this.Width);
            double scaleY = this.Height / canvasBounds.Height; //if (scaleY < 1) scaleY = -1 * (canvasBounds.Height / this.Height);
            this.RenderTransform = new ScaleTransform(scaleX, scaleY);
        }
    }

    private Rectangle canvasBounds = new Rectangle() { Width = 0, Height = 0 };

    public Tile()
    {
        this.Background = Brushes.Red;

        string xaml = "<Ellipse Name=\"Ellipse\" Width=\"80\" Height=\"80\">" +
        "    <Ellipse.Fill>" +
        "        <RadialGradientBrush RadiusX=\"0.675\" RadiusY=\"0.675\" Center=\"0.644144,0.355856\" GradientOrigin=\"0.644144,0.355856\">" +
        "            <RadialGradientBrush.GradientStops>" +
        "                <GradientStop Color=\"#FFFFFFFF\" Offset=\"0\"/>" +
        "                <GradientStop Color=\"#FF153FC4\" Offset=\"1\"/>" +
        "            </RadialGradientBrush.GradientStops>" +
        "            <RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>" +
        "                <TransformGroup/>" +
        "            </RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>" +
        "        </RadialGradientBrush>" +
        "    </Ellipse.Fill>" +
        "</Ellipse>";

        Canvas canvasFromXaml = (Canvas)XamlReader.Parse("<Canvas xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\">" + xaml + "</Canvas>");

        double maxHeight = 0;
        double maxWidth = 0;
        while (canvasFromXaml.Children.Count > 0)
        {
            UIElement e = canvasFromXaml.Children[0];
            canvasFromXaml.Children.Remove(e);

            if (double.IsNaN(Canvas.GetLeft(e))) Canvas.SetLeft(e, 0);
            if (double.IsNaN(Canvas.GetTop(e))) Canvas.SetTop(e, 0);

            Canvas.SetTop(e, 0);

            this.Children.Add(e);

            maxWidth = Math.Max((double)e.GetValue(Canvas.WidthProperty) + (double)e.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty), maxWidth);
            maxHeight = Math.Max((double)e.GetValue(Canvas.HeightProperty) + (double)e.GetValue(Canvas.TopProperty), maxHeight);
        }

        canvasBounds = new Rectangle() { Width = maxWidth, Height = maxHeight };
    }
}

public enum TileSize
{
    Small, // 50x50
    Medium, // 100x100
    Wide, // 200x100
    Large // 200x200
}
```

Comment: You do want to scale the contents to the canvas, not the other way around, correct? (Otherwise change word order in title, don't use it for prepending tags, that's not what it's for.)

Comment: You have two if statement that modify the scale if the scale is below 1 you do that for each scale separately. These clauses then give you negative the inverse of the scale you just set?? Thouse clauses are not needed if all you want is a constant scale relative to the canvasBounds.

Comment: The statements with if (scale < 1) where tests. but don't work either... ;)

And yes, i want to scale the contents of the canvas to the size of the canvas.